# Bash/cut improvement for displaying hexadecimal

Tags: bash, sed, sha256, cut

There must be a better way to do this (testing a 2-block SHA256):

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
    text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
else
    text=$1
fi
echo -n $text | shasum -a 256
echo -n $text | shasum -a 256 | sed -n 's/ */-/gp' | cut -c17,33,49,65,81,97,113,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,118,120,122,124,126,128
```

The sed inserts dashes at each character, and the cut picks up dword groupings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this does what you want: `echo -n $text | shasum -a 256 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -e 's/\(.\{16\}\)/\1-/g' -e 's/-$//'`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Just with {8\}.

Comment: I've put it up as the answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Done - thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure -- and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want:

```
echo -n "$text" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -e 's/\(.\{8\}\)/\1-/g' -e 's/-$//'
```

Comment: In the continual quest for brevity, I have reduced it to:
`echo -n $text | shasum -a 256 | sed -e 's/\(.\{8\}\)/\1-/g' -e 's/-  -//'`

Comment: And, you could shorten it further by using sed's `-E` option.  I.e. `sed -E -e 's/(.{8})/\1-/g'`  ;-)